# I am getting this SQLServerException: “The result set has no current row”

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to access the record of table "babycare" in database
But when I am execute it throws

`Exception :com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException : The result set has no current row`

I have no idea what to do.
Here is my code:

```
try 
    {

        Connection con=Database.getconnection();
         PreparedStatement pts=con.prepareStatement("select * from babyname");

         ResultSet rs=pts.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){

             System.out.println("records are "+rs.getInt(1+rs.getString(2)+rs.getString(3)+rs.getInt(4)+rs.getString(5)));   
         pts.execute();
         }
         rs.close();
```

Comment: Why do you have `pts.execute();` inside the read loop?

Comment: You might also want to close the parenthesis of `rs.getInt(1`... because your current call does not do what you think it does.

Comment: There is unclosed parenthesis, it should be `rs.getInt(1)`

Answer (score 2):

You have call executeQuery once and then read the results in loop. No need to call execute.

```
try {
        Connection con=Database.getconnection();
         PreparedStatement pts=con.prepareStatement("select * from babyname");

         ResultSet rs=pts.executeQuery();

         while(rs.next()){
             System.out.println("records are "+rs.getInt(1) +" "+rs.getString(2)+rs.getString(3)+rs.getInt(4)+rs.getString(5)));
         }
         rs.close();
    }
```

Also, there was a typo in `rs.getInt(1`, which is fixed above.

Comment: What is the exception? Can post the stacktrace?